# VBA: Application.WorksheetFunction.Max Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.  I am trying to set the maximum of a row to a variable lMax.  This variable is declared earlier by "Dim lMax".

I try running the code and get the error: "Run=time error '1004':  Method 'Cells' of object '_Global' failed.  The code that fails is as follows:

```
   lMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _
   Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(Selected_Row, 7), Cells(Selected_Row, 14).End(xlToRight))) 'Max value
```

The variable Selected_Row is the row the active row that the user was last on.  It is a Global Long variable and was declared in the beginning of the module.

Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: Add `Worksheets("Data").` before `Cells()` too, like you did for `Range()`.

Comment: All range objects including `Cells()` must have the parent defined or it will refer to the active sheet and when the outer `Range` refers to a different sheet than the active it will throw the error.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  That seemed to fix the Cells method error.  Now I am getting another one that I can't fix.  I am getting a: "run time error '1004'.  Unable to get the Max property of the WorksheetFunction class"

The code that causes this error is:
lMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max( _'Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(Selected_Row, 7), Worksheets("Data").Cells(Selected_Row, 14).End(xlToRight))) 'Max value'